# How can I extract some contents in the web-scraped csv file?

Tags: csv, web-scraping, nlp, opencsv

I am struggling with dealing with a csv file that scraped one crowdfunding website.

My goal is loading the csv file on Stata, and save it in .dta format. (Stata dataset).

Stata successfully loaded the dataset, like the screenshot I attached.
v20, v21 are variables I wanted.

In v22, I wanted to know the name of "creator". However, it is not successfully excluded. As the selected cell in the screenshot shows.
[image]
Is there any way that I can extract "name" and "id" of the creator as separate columns?

Also, in v23, I want to extract the location of each row.
[image]
However, I found the "name", "state", "short_name" are in the cell, without being extracted separately.
[image]

Would there be any way that I can load them as separate columns?

Thank you for reading my post! Any help will be appreciated:)

Comment: Also, I tried to load data using R (readr package). However, the result was the same.

Comment: please share the file, some rows. Do not share only some images.

Comment: @aborruso Thank you so much for your comments. I posted with the actual three rows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72594048/how-can-i-extract-some-contents-in-the-cells-of-web-scraped-csv-file